# Javascript alert not getting displayed

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a text box (Name) and a dropdown (Hotel).

```
<input type="text" name="lname" runat="server" id="LName" tabindex="1" onblur="if(this.value == '&nbsp;') { this.value = '&nbsp;Name'; }"
                            onfocus="if(this.value == '&nbsp;Name') { this.value = '&nbsp;'; }" value="&nbsp;Name"
                            style="color: #000000; border: 1px solid #757575; width: 234px; margin-top: 5px;" />
                        <div class="dropdownselect" style="margin: 15px 0;">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drhotel" runat="server" Style="border: 1px solid #757575; width: 234px;
                                height: 16px; *height: 18px;">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

If nothing is entered the text box will display "Name" by default.  I am trying to validate on client click using the method below:

```
 function validatecust() {
    if (document.getElementById('<%= LName.ClientID %>').value == '&nbsp;Name') {
        alert('Please enter Name');
        document.getElementById('<%= LName.ClientID %>').focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('<%= drhotel.ClientID %>').value == 'Select Hotel') {
        alert('Please select Hotel');
        document.getElementById('<%= drhotel.ClientID %>').focus();
        return false;
    }}
```

[image][image]

It is not showing alerting if I don't enter anything in the Name field.  The Hotel validation works fine.

Comment: You need to put the internal encoding of the `&nbsp;` entity in the string. I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
if (document.getElementById('<%= LName.ClientID %>').value == 'Name') {
```

Leave the whitespace! If you want to indent the text in the textbox use a css padding!

If the above thing doesnt work, i think you should use a `<asp:TextBox/>` instead of a input runat server!
Have you checked what the resulting value of `LName.ClientID` and the real Id on your input is?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if (document.getElementById('<%= LName.ClientID %>').value == '&nbsp;Name') {
```

to:

```
if (document.getElementById('<%= LName.ClientID %>').value == String.fromCharCode(160) + 'Name') {
```

Comment: try again. `&nbsp;` has a char code of 160, not 32 as I thought.